# Upper bound for prime product under Riemann hypothesis

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Theorem 8 of Rosser and Schoenfeld in their paper "Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers" says that for x>285,
$$\prod \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{p_i}{p_i-1} \leq e^\gamma \ln (x) \left(1+\frac{1}{2\ln ^2 (x)} \right),$$
what is the upper bound for $\prod \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{p_i}{p_i-1}$ under RH?  Can someone give an explicit formula like the above inequality? Thanks very much!

Comment: This is Mertens 3rd theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems).

Comment: @Savio The question asks about an improved upper bound if we can assume the riemann hypothesis.

Comment: So, the main term doesn't change. I don't know if the error term changes when using RH, but the main term don't. Maybe the term $\frac{1}{2\ln^2(x)}$ can be replaced by something smaller, but in this case the inequality will hold for $x$ larger ($285$ will increase, perhaps without much control).

Comment: The improvement of Mertens theorems under the RH is in the [Nicolas Robin Lagarias papers](http://babarlelephant.free-hoster.net/zeta/)

Comment: Nice! I was wrong about "perhaps without much control", sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Robin's 1984 paper

[image]

(Any of ?) those bounds imply the RH so it is iff.

Comment: I didn't realize that Robin had already answered this question, thanks for your help.